# Calling a function when a new row be added to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, event-handling

I have a dataframe `dd` and I want to observe this dataframe, so everytime a new row is added to this dataframe, I want to call a function (to calculate new mean value of all the columns of this datafram for instance).

How could I do that in R?

**Update**:

Sample code:

```
df = data.frame(x1=as.integer(),x2=as.integer())

df = rbind (df, c(1,2)) # --> should run a function here
```

Comment: You can check `colMeans(df1)`

Comment: You should not add many single rows to a data.frame.

Comment: Provide example data, and code, how that dataframe is getting updated with new rows.

Comment: Hi, it's just an example. The point is to know when a (or many) new row(s) are added to the dataframe.

Comment: keeping checking the dimensions of data using dim() which returns the #rows and #columns

Comment: Hi @joel.wilson, pooling is indeed a solution, but I don't think it is the best way. I just want a kind of event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using an S3 class:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = 3, x2 = 4)
class(df) <- c("autoupdateDF", class(df))

rbind.autoupdateDF <- function(DF, newrow, colFUN = mean, ...) {
  DF <- rbind.data.frame(DF, newrow, ...)
  DF[] <- lapply(DF, colFUN)
  DF
}

df <- rbind(df, c(1, 2))
#  x1 x2
#1  2  3
#2  2  3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Roland. In my case, I need to use ``print (DF)`` in the last line of the function to print it out to screen.